# How to have shop by filters in home page of magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

How to use shop by  filters in home page of magento?

I have tried using layered magento extension it is not working

Please help me with the solution

Answer (score 0):

There are many paid layered navigation extensions that can complete this task.
If you want to develop a new one, you can start from

1) adding all products to some category

2) setting this category as default at the homepage

3) inserting the `catalog/layer_view` block in the desired position at the homepage

4) updating the filter links by overwriting the `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php`